# OAuth Re-Auth Frequency Changed for Google OAuth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I've been using

https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload

to automate uploading of videos to YouTube, no other processes share the auth session, this process is the only one using the credentials.  I've been using this for years however more recently, within the last couple months, it seems like the OAuth session keeps expiring on me almost on a weekly basis.  This would break my automation and I have to re-authenticate weekly.

No updates were done to the script prior to this issue starting. Is anyone aware of any changes Google had made that may have cause this new behavior to happen?

The reproduction is as follows:

- Have sufficient route to upload videos onto YouTube API
- Use https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload to upload videos to YouTube
- When executing `youtube-upload`, it will prompt for OAuth2 authZ code, enter the code after visiting authZ webpage
- Automate the uploads (~30 videos per day)
- After a week, OAuth authZ session will expire and re-authZ will be required

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include [example] and describe the issue in detail including any errors.

Comment: I've added the repro.  It just invalidates the session after 1-2 weeks still.  no errors aside from re-auth

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] the code needs to be in your quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

> OAuth session keeps expiring on me almost on a weekly basis.

From [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration):

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

If your app is still in the testing phase your refresh token will expire every week. You need to set your application to production in google cloud console under the auth consent screen.